# Prevent browser from caching Angular views

Tags: html, angularjs

On my development environment, I have the BrowserLink configured so that whenever I make changes to HTML/JS in an angular app, the browser reloads. I've noticed that sometimes I do not see the latest changes I make. Either/Both of the following fixes it:

1. Use Ctrl F5 for the browser to force loading the assets
2. Go to tools -> clear cache

I am concerned that when the app is in production, users will have their views/controllers/services cached as well.

How do I force the browser to load the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

This is called cache busting and there are [a number of tricks you can use for it](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/).

Personally I usually work with Laravel and there I use Mix's own versioning system to version each build. That way the links to the assets point to the latest version. If you're using any Javascript build system you should be able to find a plugin for it to do that.

If all else fails a trick I sometimes use with non-Laravel PHP applications is to get a timestamp for when the file last changed and append it to the file path, as in this example:

```
<img src="<?=$path?>?v=<?=filemtime($path)?>">
```

The principle is applicable in any other language too - here's a Handlebars helper to do the same:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
Handlebars.registerHelper('version', function (path) {
    return path + '?v=' + fs.statSync(path).mtime.getTime();
});
```

It shouldn't be hard to do something similar in any other language.